# Create two column with multiple separators

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe such as

```
COl1
scaffold_97606_2-BACs_-__SP1_1
UELV01165908.1_2-BACs_+__SP2_2
UXGC01046554.1_9-702_+__SP3_3
scaffold_12002_1087-1579_-__SP4_4
```

and I would like to separate both into two columns and get :

```
COL1           COL2 
scaffold_97606 2-BACs_-__SP1_1
UELV01165908.1 2-BACs_+__SP2_2
UXGC01046554.1 9-702_+__SP3_3
scaffold_12002 1087-1579_-__SP4_4
```

so as you can see the separator changes it can be `.Number_` or  `Number_Number`

So far I wrote ;

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
    separate(COL1, paste0('col', 1:2), sep = " the separator patterns ", extra = "merge")
```

but I do not know what separator I should use here in the `" the separator patterns "`part

Comment: Just for the record: OP attempt is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62913589/3832970). It is not a mere gimme-teh-codez request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
> df1 %>%
    separate(COl1, paste0('col', 1:2), sep = "(?<=\\d)_(?=\\d+-)", extra = "merge")
            col1               col2
1 scaffold_97606    2-BACs_-__SP1_1
2 UELV01165908.1    2-BACs_+__SP2_2
3 UXGC01046554.1     9-702_+__SP3_3
4 scaffold_12002 1087-1579_-__SP4_4
```

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o39MJZ/1)

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=\d)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a digit immediately to the left  of the current location
- `_`  - an underscore
- `(?=\d+-)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more digits and then a `-` immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `extract` :

```
tidyr::extract(df, COl1, c('Col1', 'Col2'), regex = '(.*?\\d+)_(.*)')

#            Col1               Col2
#1 scaffold_97606    2-BACs_-__SP1_1
#2 UELV01165908.1    2-BACs_+__SP2_2
#3 UXGC01046554.1     9-702_+__SP3_3
#4 scaffold_12002 1087-1579_-__SP4_4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(COl1 = c("scaffold_97606_2-BACs_-__SP1_1", 
"UELV01165908.1_2-BACs_+__SP2_2", 
"UXGC01046554.1_9-702_+__SP3_3", "scaffold_12002_1087-1579_-__SP4_4"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```